# istio multicluster with muilti mesh

Tags: istio

I have one use case. in a single valuestream i have four workstream. I am planning to host the each workstream on single mesh with multi control plane on multi cluster (GKE Cluster). So now in valuestreams I have four meshes and each mesh hosted on their own multi cluster with multi control plane. I am planning to use the Admiral for automation. I also need inter mesh communication. What would be the right architecture for this? I am considering the GCP as cloud platform.

need solution and some high level diagram